# How to Deselect the image by clicking other button?

Tags: ios, uibutton

Hi in my application I ask the user to provide feedback. This could be to rate our server for example. They do this by clicking one of two buttons, good or bad. When they select an option the image for the button changes which is what I need it to do. The problem I have is that if they select good then select bad the good button needs to revert back to the 'un selected' option. As they cannot bother be 'selected'

My button code.

```
- (IBAction)gd:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else{
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)bd:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)sender;

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else{
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:YES];

    }
}
```

I have used the above but its not working like i want its showing like in the below image.

[image]

Please tell me show to resolve this one.

Comment: please, retype your question, use punctuation. it's unreadable.

Comment: @cyborg86pl i have edited my question pls check now

Answer (score 2):

Create an outlet for both buttons and set the images for both states.

```
- (void)initButtons {
   [gdBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [gdBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   [bdBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [bdBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

The actions should then look like these:

```
- (IBAction)gd:(UIButton *)sender {
   [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];
   [bdBtn setSelected:NO];
}

- (IBAction)bd:(UIButton *)sender {
   [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];
   [gdBtn setSelected:NO];
}
```

Comment: i have tried ur code in isSelect its showing error like property isSelect not found

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution**

Add this Function in the starting , to deselect 2 buttons whenever you tap on button:-

```
-(void)deselectButtons
{
    for(UIView *vw in [self.view subviews])
    {
       if([vw isKindOfClass:([UIButton class])])
       {
           UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)vw;
           btn.selected=FALSE;
       }
    }
}
```

**for Good Button:-**

```
- (IBAction)bd:(id)sender {

   [self deselectButtons];//add this line of code 

   UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)sender;

   if ([sender isSelected]) {
      [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              [sender setSelected:NO];
    } else {
       [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [sender setSelected:YES];
    }

}
```

**for BAD Button:-**

```
- (IBAction)bd:(id)sender {

   [self deselectButtons];//add this line of code      

    UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)sender;

   if ([sender isSelected]) {
      [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [sender setSelected:NO];
   } else {
      [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rd1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [sender setSelected:YES];
   }
}
```

Comment: @Vizilx i dont want to deselect both please read my question proplerly i want to delesect one when other button is selected